# Application Insights aggregate sums of event occurrences

Tags: azure-application-insights

I'm logging an event `UserRegistered` in app insights so that I can see which users have done what right from registration. I'd like to use this event to also display total users registered over time.

I currently have this query:

```
customEvents
| where timestamp >= datetime(2021-06-04T16:08:10.602Z) and timestamp < datetime(2021-06-11T16:08:10.602Z)
| summarize ['customEvents/count_sum'] = sum(itemCount) by bin(timestamp, 1d)
| order by timestamp desc
```

However this only gives me the total of each bin. So if a user registers on day 1 and two on day 3, I see something like:

```
                     |
|                    |
1         2          3
```

However, I want to see growth over time, so these bins would need to aggregate their sums, giving me this:

```
                     |
                     |
|         |          |
1         2          3
```

Can I achieve this in App Insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this ?

```
customEvents
| where timestamp >= datetime(2021-06-04T16:08:10.602Z) and timestamp < datetime(2021-06-11T16:08:10.602Z)
| summarize ['customEvents/count_sum'] = sum(itemCount) by bin(timestamp, 1d)
| order by timestamp desc
| extend total=row_cumsum(['customEvents/count_sum'])
```

Comment: I had an issue running this. With some modification though, this seems to give me what I need: `customEvents
| where timestamp >= datetime(2021-06-04T16:08:10.602Z) and timestamp < datetime(2021-06-11T16:08:10.602Z)
| summarize ['customEvents/count_sum'] = sum(itemCount) by bin(timestamp, 1d)
| serialize ['customEvents/count_sum']
| extend ['customEvents/cumsum'] = row_cumsum(['customEvents/count_sum'])
| project timestamp, ['customEvents/cumsum']
| render areachart ` . May be some unnecessary ops in there but `cumsum` seems to be what i was after

Comment: It's fine that you can find what you need, and thanks for your response.